# Captuing runtime for each task within a dataflow in SSIS2012

Tags: ssis, dataflow

In my SSIS package I have a dataflow that looks something like this.

[image]

My requirement is to log the end time of each flatfile destination (Or the time when each of the flat files is created) , in a SQL server table. To be more clear, there will be one row per flatfile in the log table. Is there any simple way(preferably) to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I ended up using a script task after the dataflow and read the creation time of each of the file created in the dataflow. I also used same script task to insert logs into the table, just to keep things in one place. For details refer the post masked as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the accurate date and timestamp of each flat file created as the destination, you'll need to create three new global variables and set up a for-each loop container in the control flow following your current data flow task and then add to the for-each loop container a script task that will read from one flat file at a time the date/time information.  That information will then be saved to one of the new global variables that can then be applied in a second SQL task (also in the for-each loop) to write the information to a database table.

The following link provides a good example of the steps you'll need to apply.  There are a few extra steps not applicable that you can easily exclude.

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/01/use-filedates-in-ssis.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used for-each(c#) loop within the script task and inserted logs by retrieving the database connection manager. Seemed a little simpler. Thanks for the idea and the link :)

Answer (score 1):

After looking more closely at the toolbox, I think the best way to do this is to move each source/destination pairing into its own dataflow and use the OnPostExecute event of each dataflow to write to the SQL table.

Comment: I'm not seeing an OnCompletion event [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140223(v=sql.105).aspx) I've used OnPostExecute.  Which version of SSIS includes OnCompletion?

Comment: OnPostExecute then.   I couldn't remember the exact name.

Comment: @TabAlleman: If I'm not wrong event handler is available only on control flow tasks, not for individual tasks within dataflow. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: No, you're right, it seems the event handlers are only on the control flow tasks.   Edited my answer.

Comment: @TabAlleman: Separating each source/destination pair into different dataflow tasks is something I'd like to avoid. Reason is I have just too many pairs to separate. But I'm surprised to find there is no easy way to handle this. But I think the answer by **user3662215** has a convincing work around.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to provide more detail to @TabAlleman's approach.
For each control flow task with a name like `Bene_hic`, you will have a source file and a destination file.
On the `'Event Handlers'` tab for that executable (use the drop-down list,) you can create the `OnPostExecute` event.

In that event, I have two SQL tasks.  One generates the SQL to execute for this control flow task, the second executes the SQL.

These SQL tasks are dependent on two user variables scoped in the `OnPostExecute` event.  The `EvaluateAsExpression` property for both is set to `True`.  The first one, `Variable1`, is used as a template for the SQL to execute and has a value like:

```
"SELECT execSQL FROM db.Ssis_onPostExecute 
where stgTable = '"  + @[System::SourceName]  +  "'"
```

`@[System::SourceName]` is an SSIS system variable containing the name of the control flow task.

I have a table in my database named `Ssis_onPostExecute` with two fields, an `execSQL` field with values like:

```
     DELETE FROM db.TableStats WHERE TABLENAME = 'Bene_hic';
        INSERT INTO db.TableStats 
             SELECT CreatorName ,t.tname, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,rcnt  FROM 
        (SELECT databasename, TABLENAME AS tname, CreatorName FROM dbc.TablesV) t  
        INNER JOIN
        (SELECT 'Bene_hic' AS tname, 
COUNT(*) AS rcnt FROM db.Bene_hic) u ON
             t.tname = u.tname 
    WHERE  t.databasename = 'db' AND t.tname = 'Bene_hic';
```

and a `stgTable` field with the name of the corresponding control flow task in the package (case-sensitive!) like `Bene_hic`

In the first SQL task (named `SQL`,) I have the `SourceVariable` set to a user variable (`User::Variable1`) and the `ResultSet` property set to `'single row.'`  The Result Set detail includes a `Result Name` = `0` and `Variable name` as the second user variable (`User::Variable2`.)

In the second SQL task (`exec`,) I have the `SQLSourceType` property set to `Variable` and the `SourceVariable` property set to `User::Variable2`.

Then the package is able to copy the data in the source object to the destination, and whether it fails or not, enter a row in a table with the timestamp and number of rows copied, along with the table name and anything else you want to track.

Also, when debugging, you have to run the whole package, not just one task in the event.  The variables won't be set correctly otherwise.

HTH, it took me forever to figure all this stuff out, working from examples on several web sites.  I'm using code to generate the SQL in the `execSQL` field for each of the 42 control flow tasks, meaning I created 84 user variables.

-Beth

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution will be:
1) drag the `OLE DB Command`  from the tool box after the Fatfile destination.
2) `Update Script` to update table with `current date` when `Flat file` destination is successful.
3) You can create a `variable` (scope is project) with value `systemdatetime`.
4) You might have to create another `variable` depending on your package construct if Success or fail

Comment: Thanks for response but your answer doesn't address my requirement. Your approach would work if I had only one flat file destination in the data flow. But I want to log endtime of EACH flat file destination WITHIN a single dataflow.

Comment: Also I looked at a 2008 R2 package, and there is no continuation after a flat file destination, except for failed rows.  In other words, there's no green arrow leaving the destination, only a red one.

Comment: @nlkasyap : you can do it by dragging OLE Command task and write update script that you do in Execute SQL task or pass datetime variable in OLE command task.

Comment: @TabAlleman: This question is for SSIS 2012 not 2008R2. Yes, there is no option in 2008R2.

Comment: So this option does exist in 2012?    Nice....this is what I started to suggest as an option in my answer, but that's when I looked at my own environment and saw that it (flat file destination) didn't have a green arrow, so I assumed it wasn't an option.   If it is an option in 2012, then this is the solution I would use.

Comment: @nlkasyap, I would implement this by adding an OLEDB Command component after EACH of your flat file destinations.   Not just one for the whole dataflow task.

Comment: Guys, There is just no continuation after Flat file destination, no failed rows or otherwise. Flat file destination is the DEAD END. Not sure how you're able to see an extension.